# Mount MariaDB data in a separate directory on RHEL 8?

Tags: linux, mariadb, redhat

We are migrating from a CentOS 7 server (physical server) to RHEL 8 (Azure server). This server was setup by someone else, and admittedly I know enough to install/configure LAMP. I am not a sysadmin.

That said, here is the output of `df -h` on the current server:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          16G  1.5M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                          16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vglocal00-root00  270G  156G  115G  58% /
/dev/sda1                     477M  225M  249M  48% /boot
/dev/mapper/vglocal00-tmp00   2.0G  388M  1.6G  21% /tmp
```

You'll notice the main storage is used in /.

Here's the new server we are trying to migrate to:

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                    16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       16G   25M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv  2.0G  323M  1.7G  16% /
/dev/mapper/rootvg-usrlv    10G  3.9G  6.2G  39% /usr
/dev/sda1                  496M  229M  267M  47% /boot
/dev/mapper/rootvg-homelv 1014M   50M  965M   5% /home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-varlv   8.0G  8.0G  280K 100% /var
/dev/sdc1                  256G  1.9G  255G   1% /data
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmplv   2.0G   47M  2.0G   3% /tmp
/dev/sda15                 495M  5.8M  489M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1                  147G   32K  140G   1% /mnt
```

You'll see the largest storage is on `/data`.

Since the biggest file hogs on the current server are the DB's, I was thinking I could put the DB's and their nightly backups on /data and leave everything else as-is. Is this a mistake? Or should the server be reconfigured? `/var` currently has a LARGE file in it that I can delete so it'll be much smaller.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35583/managing-a-growing-database-in-the-long-run-10-years-from-now/35618#35618) isn't exactly a duplicate, but might answer your question. Incidentally, you probably won't want to put backups on the same disk as data, for many reasons.

Comment: `/data/mariadb` is fine, just do a [few basic steps to selinux relabel that directory](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/selinux/#setting-the-file-context-for-the-data-directory). and put `datadir=/data/mariadb` in your mariadb configuration file.

Comment: @mustaccio The DB is replicated to other servers. I just make a daily backup JIC. Thx!

Comment: @danblack Thx fr the feedback!

Comment: Each replica can independently have its own disk layout.